# How to intercept GRPC response

Tags: flutter, grpc, interceptor

I am using flutter for my mobile application. I can intercept requests. But I don't know how to intercept response in GRPC in flutter.

How can I intercept GRPC response in flutter?

Answer (score 6):

It looks it is pretty easy.
First:

```
class LoggerInterceptor extends ClientInterceptor {
  static final LoggerInterceptor _instance = LoggerInterceptor._();
  static LoggerInterceptor get instance => _instance;

  LoggerInterceptor._();

  @override
  ResponseFuture<R> interceptUnary<Q, R>(
      ClientMethod<Q, R> method, Q request, CallOptions options, ClientUnaryInvoker<Q, R> invoker) {
    logger.d(
      'Grpc request. '
      'method: ${method.path}, '
      'request: $request',
    );
    final response = super.interceptUnary(
      method,
      request,
      options,
      invoker,
    );

    response.then((r) {
      logger.d(
        'Grpc response. '
        'method: ${method.path}, '
        'response: ${Utils.getSubstring(r.toString(), 3000)}',
      );
    });

    return response;
  }
}
```

Second: While creating client add interceptor to the interceptors:

```
 myClient = SomeServiceClient(
          clientChannel,
          interceptors: [
            InfoInterceptor.instance,
            LoggerInterceptor.instance,
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: how to intercept streams?